# Cannot Convert from Char to LPWSTR

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am trying to run program mentioned in :
https://www.functionx.com/visualc/controls/listcontrol.htm
by VS2015(VC++ MFC)

cannot convert from 'char [20]' to 'LPWSTR'

This is  code that cause this error:

```
void CDeptStore2Dlg::OnBnClickedNewitem()
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    CNewStoreItemDlg dlg;
    srand( (unsigned)time(NULL) );
    char strNumber[20];

    int number1 = rand() % 999;
    int number2 = rand() % 999;

    sprintf(strNumber, "%d-%d", number1, number2);
    dlg.m_ItemNumber = strNumber;

    if( dlg.DoModal() )
    {
        LVITEM lvItem;

        lvItem.mask = LVIF_TEXT;
        lvItem.iItem = 0;
        lvItem.iSubItem = 0;
        lvItem.pszText = strNumber;
        this->m_StoreItems.InsertItem(&lvItem);
    }
}
```

I searched  google for solving this problem but i got no success

Comment: `I searched google for solving this problem but i got no success` - I don't believe you, because the first result for searching "cannot convert from 'char [20]' to 'LPWSTR'" is a bunch of StackOverflow questions that answer it precisely.

Comment: i searched google and found another questions here and another site but i got no success even after trying those solutions,

Comment: Make it `wchar_t strNumber[20];` and `swprintf(strNumber, L"%d-%d", number1, number2);` (note the `w`).

Comment: thanks but i got this error :'swprintf': function has been changed to conform with the ISO C standard, adding an extra character count parameter. To use the traditional Microsoft version, set _CRT_NON_CONFORMING_SWPRINTFS

Comment: _but i got no success even after trying those solutions_: you should talk to us about this....

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using MFC, I would suggest to use `CString` class and its [Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cstringt-class?view=msvc-170#format) method.

Comment: thanks.i read you link info and it seems that is not easy to use it.can you write a example that how should i use it?

Answer (score 0):

There are new versions of several string and memory functions, intended to provide secure buffer management, basically avoiding overruns. The older original C functions (eg `strcpy()`, `sprintf()` etc) cause not just warnings, but errors with the newer versions of the libraries. It may be an option to consider, to disable these errors (as suggested by the compiler) if you are compiling (correct) old code.

The Unicode ("wide"), "secure", and default-locale equivalent of `sprintf()` is [**`swprintf_s()`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/sprintf-s-sprintf-s-l-swprintf-s-swprintf-s-l?view=msvc-170). So your code could become:

```
#include <wchar.h>
.
.
wchar_t strNumber[20];
swprintf_s(strNumber, 20, L"%d-%d", number1, number2);
```

or better yet:

```
swprintf_s(strNumber, sizeof(strNumber)/sizeof(strNumber[0]), L"%d-%d", number1, number2);
```

However it can become even simpler, thanks to some inline defines in the header files. This is possible because the buffer size is known at compile time in this case:

```
swprintf_s(strNumber, L"%d-%d", number1, number2);
```

That is, you can omit the buffer size parameter; the `swprintf_s()` syntax is just like `sprintf()`'s here.

Comment: thank you so much.this is best answer that i received and also this code worked perfectly.